# python - How to use map to call a method

Tags: python, dictionary

I defined a method called Kkill：

```
def kill(proc_pid):
process = psutil.Process(proc_pid)
for proc in process.children(recursive=True):
    proc.kill()
process.kill()
```

Then I want to use map () to do something like:

```
kill(x) for x in RunPid
```

I used `map (kill, Runpid)` But it doesn't work

How could I perform this kind of manipulation with map?

Thanks!

Comment: don't use `map` for side effect functions. The fact that you're using python 3 doesn't help: use `list(map (kill, Runpid))` if you really want to do that.

Comment: Why you don't use `for` loop just you said?

Comment: Thanks, I'm used to using map () to do some multithreading, similar to pool.map (WantTodo, enumerate (someList)).Maybe I got a detour.

Comment: multithreading `map` is different: it uses several processors. Here it's the same processor used for loop or not. Check the duplicate link, lots of good answers there.

Comment: Thank you . I'm going to see it